# sharedPreferences.getString() return null

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to display the user email in a textView using SharedPreferences.

Shared preferences is created in loginActivity.
I try to access it from mainActivity.

My session using sharedPreference work well (with a login boolean saved in sharedPreferences files).

So what's wrong?
- A context error?
- Because I try to access the data from an another activity?

Please help :) Thanks a lot!

Here is the code im using :

- Login Activity :

  ```
  @Override
     protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
  //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
  loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF,   false);

  //If we will get true
  if(loggedIn){
      //We will start the Profile Activity
      Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
  }

  ...

  //Creating a shared preference in a login()
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

  //Adding values to editor
  editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
  editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

  //Saving values to editor
  editor.commit();
  ...
  ```
- Main Activity :

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
  email_session = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "Private");
  usernameText.setText(email_session);


  }
  ```

Comment: Sorry for the question... what exactly returns null? The string it fetches cannot be null, because your default value is set to "Private". Do you mean you get null pointer exception for calling getString on null object reference? So does that mean sharedPreferences object is null?

Comment: Sorry, yes i get null pointer exception for calling setText(email_session)

Comment: So the null pointer exception is on setText or on getString? Because those are two different objects. which one is null? The textView or the SharedPreferences?

Comment: On the setText. So it means error come from my textView and not my SharedPreferences. I think, I lack perspective on my work nad little tired. Thanks to help me :)

Comment: You haven't instantiated your TextView called useranmeText. Just find it by id and you're good to go.

Comment: i did onCreate : usernameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameView);

Comment: Could be the id is wrong. Or the text view is not a child of your content view.

Comment: Yes, indeed the textview is not a child of the currrent view. It come from a linearLayout who is called from a drawer layout (a slide menu) . Where instantiate it ?

Comment: Well it depends... is that layout a child layout or included on the activity content view? If not... is it a fragment layout? You need to somehow get to that layout from your content view. Or if you're in fragment, from the view you inflate in onCreateView method.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.  You helped me so much :) Big Thanks ! I need rest but I    will update the post when i will finish. Again Thanks !

Comment: Finally : NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
        usernameText = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.usernameView); It's working :) THanksssssssssssssssssssssss !!!

Comment: My pleasure!!! Good coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

to read the stored preferences you need to do:

## to save

```
SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs_name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
editor.putString("myTextViewValue", prefVal); //
editor.commit();
```

## to read it

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String storedPreference = preferences.getStr("myTextViewValue", null);
```

Comment: Same error. My save is like you and I try with "getPreferences" instead of "getSharedPreferences"  to read but didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your value is not stored in the shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("your Pref Name", 0) // 0 for Private Mode
String name = pref.getString("your key store when login", null); // null is the default value you can put it here "No value". then you will not get null pointer.
```